# Why is my centering style not working although centering has been directed, and as important?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I refactored (actually, started over with a new starting page) my html, because it had gotten very Rube Goldberg-esque. I made the HTML "skeleton" as basic and simple as possible.

Now, though, my "header" (just a row, really) is not centering, although I'm telling it to, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center !important;">
        <h1 runat="server" id="fakeJumbotron">FLIX 4 FAMS (Flicks for Families)</h1>
        <h5 runat="server" style="color: darkgoldenrod">Select the <span style="color: 
            green">Criteria</span> you want to filter by and then tap or click the "Search" button
        </h5>
    </div>
    . . .
```

[image]

The only other place this div is referred to is one line in the code-behind (Page_Load event):

```
fakeJumbotron.Attributes.Add("style", "font-family: \"Lucida Sans\", \"Courier\";text-shadow: -4px 
                           4px 3px #999999;font-weight:bold;color:blue;font-variant: small-caps;");
```

Notice I have the *style="text-align: center !important;"* in the div in the HTML (aspx file).

If I put the centering in the code-behind file, nothing changes, either - the text still hugs the left edge.

The only CSS I'm using at present is bootstrap:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flix 4 Fams</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
                                       bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
```

The only bootstrap classes I'm using right now are *container*, *row*, *col-2*, and *col-8*

Why is my centering not being applied, and what must I do to get it to work?

Comment: row make the element a flexbox container so you need justify-content:center (or align-items:center)

Comment: You likely want `text-align` to apply to the `h1` and `h5` elements, no? Generally, it's best not to mess with Bootstrap styles unless you know what you're doing. I would highly recommend using an external stylesheet as well.

Comment: <div class="row" style="justify-content:center"> works just fine, thanks.